# Is knowledge about noexcept-ness supposed to be forwarded when passing around a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I have written the following code to test `noexcept` propagation across function calls, and it seems that it doesn't work as I would have thought. In GCC 4.7.2, A function can effectively be tested against being `noexcept` only directly or when passed as a template specialization argument; but *not* when passed as an argument to a templated function, or as a function pointer to a normal function -- even when that function declares its formal parameter as being `noexcept`. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define test(f) \
    std::cout << __func__ << ": " #f " is " \
              << (noexcept(f()) ? "" : "not ") \
              << "noexcept\n";

template <void(*f)()>
static inline void test0() {
    test(f);
}

template <typename F>
static inline void test1(F f) {
    test(f);
}

static inline void test2(void(*f)()) {
    test(f);
}

static inline void test3(void(*f)()noexcept) {
    test(f);
}

void f1() {}
void f2() noexcept {}

int main() {
    test(f1);
    test(f2);
    test0<f1>();
    test0<f2>();
    test1(f1);
    test1(f2);
    test2(f1);
    test2(f2);
    test3(f1);
    test3(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's output:

```
main: f1 is not noexcept
main: f2 is noexcept
test0: f is not noexcept
test0: f is noexcept
test1: f is not noexcept
test1: f is not noexcept
test2: f is not noexcept
test2: f is not noexcept
test3: f is not noexcept
test3: f is not noexcept
```

Why is `noexcept`ness not propagated in other cases? In case of `test1`, the whole function is "instantiated" with the proper type of `F`, the compiler surely knows at that time whether F is a `noexcept` function. Why is it possible to write `test3` the way I wrote it, when the `noexcept`ness declaration is completely ignored?

Does the standard have to say something specific about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17, `noexcept` is finally added to the type system.  A pointer to non-`noexcept` function cannot be implicitly converted to pointer to `noexcept` function. (But the other way around is permitted).

clang 3.9.0 with `-std=c++1z`, and g++ 7.0 with `-std=c++17`, reject the line `test3(f1);`.

Answer (score 6):

Section 15.4.13 of the C++11 standard states that "an exception-specification is not considered part of a function's type".