# Enforce "noexcept" on std::function?

Tags: c++, function, noexcept

This code compiles and runs, throwing the `int`:

```
#include <functional>

void r( std::function<void() noexcept> f ) { f(); }

void foo() { throw 1; }

int main()
{
    r(foo);
}
```

However I would like the compiler to reject the line `r(foo);` because `r` should only be passed a `noexcept` function. The `noexcept` specifier appears to be ignored. Is there any way to achieve that?

Edit: This question is different to [Is knowledge about noexcept-ness supposed to be forwarded when passing around a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003502/is-knowledge-about-noexcept-ness-supposed-to-be-forwarded-when-passing-around-a) because I am asking for a remedy, specifically in the case of `std::function`.

Comment: Possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003502/is-knowledge-about-noexcept-ness-supposed-to-be-forwarded-when-passing-around-a?rq=1

Comment: @JonathanPotter certainly related, although I don't think it answers my question (Is there any way to cause `r(foo)` to be rejected)

Comment: If `noexcept` isn't part of the function's type then I'd guess not.

Comment: I also have this problem. I have an function that will complete asynchronously, and the handler provider wants to indicate that it's exception won't propagate. Is this an over site?

Comment: Looks like even with C++11 noexcept, exception specification is not still a reliable part of C++ :-(

Comment: The code in the question has stopped compiling in clang 4.0 and gcc 7.0 ( seem to have compiled fine in earlier releases ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also stumbled across this problem. My solution was to use a delegating object (delegating to the `std::function`). The delegate has a no-except specification. It could still be improved (move added, etc.).

Here it goes:

```
#include <functional>

template <class FuncT>
struct NoExceptDelegate;

template <class R, class ... Args >
struct NoExceptDelegate<R(Args...)>
{
    NoExceptDelegate(std::function<R(Args...)>&& callback)
      : callback_(move(callback))
    {
        if (!callback_)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument( "NoExceptDelegate requires a valid callback");
        }
    }

    template <class...ArgsU>
    R operator()(ArgsU&&... args) noexcept
    {
        return callback_(std::forward<ArgsU>(args)...);
    }

  private:
      std::function<R(Args...)> callback_;
};
```

This is typically used as a contract in an asynchronous interface to indicate that the provided handler shall not throw e.g.:

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void doSomethingAsynchronous(
        NoExceptDelegate<void(int)> onCompletionResult) = 0;
    //...etc
};
```

As the client is the callback provider, `NoExceptDelegate` is a promise from the provider that provided shall not fail. The provider should ensure that at least `std::function` provided is callable.

Comment: That's not really correct though, as std::function may throw bad_function_call for empty std::functions.

Comment: In that case one could catch it during construction, which is not during invocation.

Comment: Yep seems reasonable enough to me to prevent nullability as an invariant.

Comment: What compiler does this work on? It did not work for me using g++ -std=c++11 with g++ version 5.4.0.

Comment: @KurtM, at that stage I tested it on GCC 4.8 and the compiler shipped with Visual Studio, as well as the latest clang at the time that it was written

Comment: Is it correct to assume that there is no way to make this a compile time guarantee ? I.e. a promise is the best we can do ?

Comment: @Zitrax, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763401/can-a-noexcept-function-still-call-a-function-that-throws-in-c17 answers your question, which boils down to - yes, the promise is presently the best. BTW, kudos for fixing the code...

Comment: The `operator()` method should also be marked `const`. I also think, IMO, that there should be a default constructor which fills `callback_` with an empty lambda, such as `[](){}`, just for ease-of-transition from `std::function`.