# How will C++17 exception specifier type system work?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, noexcept

Studying about "noexcept specifier(and operator)", I wrote a simple code. And I am surprised that this piece of code:

```cpp
void asdf() noexcept {}
int main() 
{
    auto f = asdf;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << noexcept(f()) << std::endl;
}
```

prints `false`, even function "asdf" is noexcept-specified.

So while searching why this mysterious phenomenon is happening, I found C++17's "exception specifier type system"- [P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html).

According to this (accepted) proposal, since C++17; as `noexcept` is part of function type, will the code above print `true`?

And one more, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602903/enforce-noexcept-on-stdfunction) question's one line:

```cpp
std::function<void() noexcept> f
```

The `noexcept` specifying seems ignored in C++14 or 11.
Will this code work as intended in C++17?

Comment: g++ return `true` for `noexcept(f())` without `-std=c++1z` (but clang does return `false`).

Comment: For extra fun, change `auto f = asdf;` to `void(*f)() noexcept = asdf;`. Now GCC prints `false` while clang prints `true`.

Comment: @Holt Thanks for information. I am using MSVC(returns `false`). What would be different of them? Is that a bug of g++ or C++14 or earlier standard specified nothing about `noexcept` type system?

Comment: @hvd For that code, MSVC prints `true`. I'm so confused now :p

Comment: @hvd With the function pointer version, if you remove the `noexcept` on `asdf`, clang rejects the affectation but gcc does not complain... I am guessing gcc ignore `noexcept` on function pointer declaration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> According to this (accepted) proposal, since C++17; as noexcept is part of function type, will the code above print `true`?

**Yes.**

The type of `f` will be deduced to `void(*)() noexcept` since the function-to-pointer conversion applied to `asdf` will preserve the `noexcept` property. A call to a `noexcept` function pointer certainly cannot throw an exception, unless one of its subexpressions does.

For the exact wording, see [[expr.unary.noexcept]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.noexcept#3) and [[expect.spec]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#13). Note that the new wording in the latter paragraph from the C++17 draft comes from P0012R1, which is linked in the OP.

> The result of the `noexcept` operator is `true` if the set of potential exceptions of the expression ([except.spec]) is empty, and `false` otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> - If `e` is a function call ([expr.call]):
>
>   - If its *postfix-expression* is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* ([expr.prim.id]), class member access ([expr.ref]), or pointer-to-member operation ([expr.mptr.oper]) whose *cast-expression* is an *id-expression*, *S* is the set of types in the exception specification of the entity selected by the contained *id-expression* (after overload resolution, if applicable).
>       ...

So the set of potential exceptions of `f()` is the same as the set of types in the exception specification of `f`, which is empty since `f` is declared `noexcept`.

Let's move on to the second question:

> The `noexcept` specifying seems ignored in C++14 or 11. Will this code work as intended in C++17?

Your question seems to be: will `std::function<void() noexcept>` refuse to hold a function that can throw exceptions?

I would say that it's **unclear.** In the present wording of the standard, `std::function<void() noexcept>` is not actually defined, just as [`std::function<double(float) const>` is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654186/trait-to-drop-const-from-a-member-function-type). This was of course not an issue in C++14, since `noexcept` was not considered part of a function's type.

Will `std::function<void() noexcept>` simply break in C++17? That's uncertain to me. Let's take a look at the current wording to guess what the behaviour "should" be.

The standard requires the argument to the constructor of `std::function<R(ArgTypes..)>` to be "Lvalue-Callable" for argument types `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`, which [means](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func#2):

> A callable type ([func.def]) `F` is *Lvalue-Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R` if the expression `INVOKE(declval<F&>(), declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause [expr]), is well formed ([func.require]).

Perhaps there should be an additional requirement that if the function type is `noexcept`, then `noexcept(INVOKE(...))` must be true as well. Nonetheless, this wording is not present in the current draft.

In P0012R1, there is a comment that:

> It is an open issue how to propagate "noexcept" through `std::function`.

My guess is that they mean that it is not clear how `std::function` could be implemented if this additional requirement were imposed. Hopefully, someone else can provide more details.

Comment: Clearly we need a `std::function_moveonly` and `std::function_noexceptonly` and `std::function_moveonly_noexceptonly`.  But what about `std::function_mutablecall`?  This could get messy.

Comment: Just commenting to see if people have more up to date observations on this, without making a new question