# Can a noexcept function still call a function that throws in C++17?

Tags: c++, exception, function-pointers, c++17, noexcept

In [P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html), "*Make exception specifications be part of the type system*",
I see that `noexcept` is now becoming a part of the function type.

I can't tell whether this will prevent `noexcept(true)` functions from still being able to call `noexcept(false)` functions.

Will the following code still be valid for C++17?

```
void will_throw() noexcept(false){
  throw 0;
}

void will_not_throw() noexcept(true){
  will_throw();
}
```

Comment: What if the throwing function is inside a `try...catch` in the noexcept function?

Comment: `noexcept` means that a function _will_ not throw, not that it _cannot_ throw, and the penalty for failure to comply is calling `std::terminate`, not UB. So yes, that code is legal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> Note that a `noexcept` specification on a function is not a compile-time
>   check; it is merely a method for a programmer to inform the compiler
>   whether or not a function should throw exceptions.

So the syntax of your code is valid, but [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) will be called when executed.

Comment: Do any compiler-flags exist that at least emit a warning for this type of behaviour?

Comment: Considering that `noexcept` is not a compile-time check, it doesn't seem possible to ask compiler to generate a warning.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately it is valid at compile time.

Although *noexcept* is used by the compiler to optimize the exception handling code, making the code more performant, it's a shame they didn't push it further to give *noexcept* a semantic meaning.

Ideally, when you mark a method as *noexcept* it should *also mean* that the method is not supposed to let any exceptions bubble up. So if you have a method marked as *noexcept* but it calls other methods that are not marked as *noexcept*, that should give you a compile error, unless there is a *try/catch* block surrounding anything that can throw.

Simply calling *std::terminate* is a very poor language design choice, because it doesn't put any responsibility at the hands of whoever writes the *noexcept* method. On the contrary, it harms software reuse by making it impossible even to the consumer to work the problem around.

For example, say that I am a bad library developer and I wrote the following code:

Header file *Foo.h* that ships with my library:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething() noexcept;
};
```

You are happy consumer of *FooLib* writing a Bar application:

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    try
    {
        foo.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Yay!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That code compiles fine and runs fine until you have Foo throwing an exception... And it doesn't make any difference if you enclose the call to *foo.DoSomething()* with a *try/catch* block. The code will simply abort.

If you don't have the code of Foo, you can't fix it. The only solution in this case is to throw away Foo library and write your own.

The contents of Foo.cpp can be something like this:

```
static void PotentiallyThrowException()
{
    throw 0;
}

void Foo::DoSomething() noexcept
{
    PotentiallyThrowException();
}
```

Note that it's up to the implementer of *Foo::DoSomething()* to wrap their own calls into *try/catch*. But due to the same issue, if they are calling other methods that are marked as *noexcept* and those developers didn't do the same, now it's *Foo::DoSomething()* that is hosed. And so on, and so forth.

We can safely say that from the semantic point of view *noexcept* is not only useless, but it's also harmful.

Comment: Thank you, at last I understand why I've never used exception qualifiers before and don't plan on using them in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`noexcept(true)` functions can call `noexcept(false)` functions.  There will be a runtime error if an exception is thrown.  The canonical example of why this is allowed is:

```
double hypotenuse(double opposite, double adjacent) noexcept(true)
{
    return std::sqrt(opposite*opposite + adjacent*adjacent);
}
```

`std::sqrt` will throw `domain_error` if its argument is negative, but clearly that will never happen here.

(In an ideal world, it would be forbidden by default with an `exception_cast` to allow it where required.  The result could either be UB if an exception is thrown, or std::terminate).

Answer (score 2):

Including the exception specification in the function type is orthogonal to whether a function can call another function with an incompatible exception specification (without handling the exceptions that were not included in its exception specification). The former is about type safety with respect to function pointers (so that you cannot call a throwing function through a function pointer that was known not to throw). Regarding the latter, we can either prohibit it during compilation (as in Java), or treat it as a runtime error (leading to the termination of the program, as is chosen for the C++ current standard).

One may argue by brining the analogy of calling a non-`const` (non-static) member function from a `const` (non-static) member function. However the difference is that indirectly modifying an object inside a non-`const` member function called through a `const` member function would go undetected (or else would be too costly to detect) and may lead to nasty bugs, that's why it has to be prevented during compilation. Whereas the act of throwing an exception is (should be) an exceptional event and we can afford inserting run-time checks of whether the exception complies with the exception specification and should be let out, or it violates the program logic and should instead terminate the program.